# Popup menu : items reachable from the actionbar instead of the "menu button" of the device

Tags: android, popup, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-menu

I have in my application a ListView activity called ResultListViewActivity and which display contents from a database. The content displayed in the listview depends on a button clicked in a previous activity. So if the user clicks the "Button 1" in the Main Activity, it will display a specific content in ResultListViewActivity, and so on.

I want to add a menu to this activity : the thing is, the items of this menu are also supposed to change according to the button clicked before. There are 9 cases, each cases has a different number of items. So far I have this code :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    int filterVariable = bundle.getInt("filterVariable");
    switch (filterVariable) 
    {
    case 1:
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.filter_fastfood, menu);
        break;

    case 2:
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.filter_restaurants, menu);
        break;

    case 3: 
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.filter_coffeeshops, menu);
        break;

    case 4:
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.filter_bars, menu);
        break;

// [... and so on]
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

It works well, for every case I indeed have my different items in the menu. But I don't want these items to be reachable through the "menu button" of my device (which is absolutely not instinctive and hard for the user to guess). These items are importants so I would like to have a button on the upper right corner, which would open this menu instead (drop down menu / pop up menu).

Do you know how such a thing can be done ? I have seen this in some google application but couldn't find tutorial showing which tools to use for doing this.
Thanks !

ps: I am using actionbarsherlock in my application.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest version 4.2.0 of ABS, then support for `.ForceOverflow` themes has been removed.

**Source:** [Version 4.2.0 Changelog](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#readme)

Extract of the Change Log:

```
Add SearchView widget for standard search interaction (API 8+ only)
Fix: ShareActionProvider in the split action bar no longer fills the entire screen.
Fix: ShareActionProvider now does file I/O on a background thread.
Fix: Automatically correct ColorDrawable not respecting bounds when used as a stacked background.
Fix: Ensure fragments collection is present before dispatching events.
Fix: XML-defined onClick searches the correct context for the declared method.
Fix: Ensure action mode start/finish callbacks are invoked on the activity for the native action bar.
Fix: Allow tab callbacks to have a fragment transaction instance for any FragmentActivity.
Fix: Ensure CollapsibleActionView callbacks are dispatched in both native and compatbility action bars.
Fix: Remove .ForceOverflow themes. These never should have been included.
```

To workaround that, you will need to download an older version (version 4.1.0) of ABS that had it working. You can get a list of download as per their release history here: http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html

*This is from a production app, tested and functioning.*

You will also need to make a minor change in your applications default theme. For example:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ForceOverflow">
    <item name="absForceOverflow">true</item>
</style>
```

Note the use of `@style/Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow` in the `parent` attribute for the primary theme. Also not the additional `<style>` with the name of `MyTheme.ForceOverflow`. Doing the above will get the Overflow menu working for you.

You will also need to add this attribute to your menu items:

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```

Now, to force the device into thinking that it has a *physical* menu key, use this code:

*NOTE: **This is a hack** and for the obvious lack of access to multiple devices, I have personally never tested if it works on every Android device that exists. Use at your own risk etc. FYI, I have used this before and it worked with no complaints till date.*

```
try {
    ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(MainPage.this);
    Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
    if (menuKeyField != null) {
        menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
        menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

*Forcing the Overflow Menu to appear in the `ActionBar` as against not showing an indicator that more options exist is a personal preference. I am answering this from the stand point of a technically possible solution as against promoting the use of such a feature. Whether it is advisable from the UX point of view is another subject matter.*

Comment: Wow thanks, I am a bit disappointed and upset that it has to be a hack and there is no cleaner way to do this. When I checked the ActionBarSherlock demo on the play store, there was this demonstration of "Sub-menus" doing exactly what I wanna do and it was implying that it was an obvious thing to do.

Comment: @Phalanx: read the second edit in this answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13307583/450534

Comment: Thx, I took a look but I feel it's gonna be a too complicated path to take as I am still a beginner. I am gonna explore this way instead : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483612/popup-menu-on-click-of-a-button-in-action-bar  Seems to fit with my needs !

Comment: @Phalanx: it may sound complicated, but it really is a one time thing. But good luck anyway. :-)